# How do I allow the user to choose between two options?

Tags: python, input

So as of now, I need to write a script prompting a user to select either
1 or 2, 1 creates makes the turtle draw a triangle, and 2 makes it draw a square, so far what I have is.

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()

rex = turtle.Turtle()
rex.pensize(2)
rex.pencolor("black")
rex.fillcolor("white")
rex.pendown()
rex.begin_fill()

print (40 * '-')
print ("Click Either 1 or 2 To Chose Which To Draw")
print (40 * '-')
print ("1. Triangle")
print ("2. Square")


choice = input('Enter your choice [1-2] : ')
choice = int(choice)

if choice == 1:
    rex.forward(90)
    rex.left(120)
    rex.forward(90)
    rex.left(120)
    rex.forward(90)
    rex.left(120)
    rex.end_fill()
    rex.penup()
elif choice == 2:
    rex.forward(100)
    rex.left(90)
    rex.forward(100)
    rex.left(90)
    rex.forward(100)
    rex.left(90)
    rex.forward(100)
    rex.left(90)
    rex.end_fill()
    rex.penup()
```

I run the script, and what comes out in the shell is:

```
Click Either 1 or 2 To Chose Which To Draw
1. Triangle
2. Square
Enter your choice [1-2] :
```

however, after the colon if you type 1 or 2, nothing on turtle happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your program works correctly but it ends before displaying the output. You should pause the control of the program so that user can see the output first. Best way is to add the following one line of code at the end of your program -

```
window.exitonclick()
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.exitonclick).

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply, however I added that and when the shell comes up prompting the user to enter 1, or 2 the python graphic crashes, it stops responding, do you know what may be causing that?

Comment: Yes, that is expected but as soon as you input the choice it will start responding again.

Comment: Is the person supposed to input 1 or 2 in the shell or with the window activated? Either way it continues to not respond(thank you for extended help either way!) could it just be a bug on my computers end?

Comment: In the shell, i.e., the window where the prompt `Enter your choice [1-2] : ` is displayed.

Comment: So I got that, but when I type in the number the turtle does not move, is there a reason for that? Does the person need to hit 'enter' after typing 1 or 2? Sorry this is such basic stuff but this just won't work for me xD.

Comment: Yes, you need to press Enter after inputting the choice.

Comment: Strange.. still doesn't make the turtle start to draw with either of the numbers.. is it just an issue on my end? Ill stop asking since you've probably said everything you can to help me.. I don't know what's wrong the turtle just wont move.

Comment: Figured it out, thank you so much for your help I spaced something out when I was asking questions.. >_< THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped. You can accept and upvote my answer then :)